# Parse server giving unauthorised (401) while login in iOS 8 using AFNetworking

Tags: parse-platform, ios8, afnetworking-2, unauthorized, afhttprequestoperation

Hi I'm working on iOS sync component for saving data in parse server , i created a class from the parse web end and named the class as TicketDetail and added some fields with data, but when i try accessing the class from my app using AFNetworking GET request with link https://api.parse.com/1/ also passing AppID and client Key as header fields with the AFHTTPRequestOperation. Before making the request I'm checking if the user is registered with parse.com using below code

```
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password
                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        if (user) {
                                            // Do stuff after successful login.
                                            NSLog(@"%@",user);
                                            NSLog(@"%@",user.email);
                                            NSLog(@"%@",user.username);
                                            [[AFSyncEngine sharedInstance] startSync];

                                        } else {
                                            NSLog(@"The login failed. Check error to see why");
                                            UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unauthorised User" message:@"Would you like to SignUp" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"SignUp", nil];
                                            _alert.tag=89;
                                            [_alert show];
                                            };
                                    }];
```

if the user is not authorised, them i signing up the user using below code

```
PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
[newUser setUsername:self.userNameFld.text];
[newUser setEmail:self.emailIdFld.text];
[newUser setPassword:self.passwordFld.text];
[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Registered");
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SignUp" message:@"Successfull" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}];
```

once the user is registered and tried to login this is the response I'm getting from parse server

2015-03-09 14:44:49.742 MyDetails[2360:1369317] Error
     Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7fbf585c0f40 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=
        { URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TicketDetail } 
      { status     code: 401,
        headers 
       {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "*";
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
         Connection = "keep-alive";
        "Content-Length" = 25;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Date = "Mon, 09 Mar 2015 09:14:47 GMT";
        Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
        "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Parse\"";
         "X-Parse-Platform" = G1;
        "X-Runtime" = "0.000162";
         } },
         NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TicketDetail, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a22756e 61757468 6f72697a 6564227d 0a>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}

Please help me out if anyone worked on parse.com and AFNetworking

Answer (score 2):

In AFNetworking you need to add the security policy for the https requests.

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
self.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: This how I'm doing, but still nothing working out AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;self.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;[self setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" forHTTPHeaderField:kParseAPIApplicationId]; [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" forHTTPHeaderField:kParseAPIKey];

Comment: If the above doesn't work You're mostly using wrong App ID and Client Key.